# Probablity of Having equal number of people in two room

Tags: probability

We have two rooms and ten people. Two initial states are Room A- 10 People, Room B -0 and Room A-9 People, Room B-1 person. Every minute, a person is chosen at random and (s)he must swap thier room. What is the probablity that as time tends to infinity, both rooms have 5 people each.

This is clearly a first order Markov chain which i solved using Matrix method and a bit of Mathematica.

Is there any other, more intuituve way for this?

The answer is about $0.2461$ for anyone wondering

Comment: I am not sure how the game works, since Monte-Carlo Testing does not seem to confirm your figure.

Comment: @String I'm not sure what that is. Could you elaborate why this is not conforming? Also, both initial states are equally likely